# Conversão de formato 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z de campo time.Time

Tags: formatação, time, golang

Estou utilizando o ORM [gorm](http://gorm.io) para um projeto, e nas colunas referente as datas, conforme documentação, é necessário setar o tipo **time.Time** nos campos das Structs que abstraem datas.

O retorno dessas colunas geradas pelo ORM, vem no padrão `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z` (do tipo time.Time). Como exatamente consigo formatar essa estrutura para outro formato como `0001-01-01 00:00:00` e vice-versa (transformar outro formato para este que ele está usando por padrão)?

Tentei vários exemplos que encontrei na internet, mas nenhum trabalhava com esse formato em específico, e não tive sucesso com algumas dinâmicas que vi em alguns outros tópicos, trabalhando com o parse de outros formatos, já que não encontrei nenhum exemplo prático que tenha esse formato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se ele já é um `time.Time` você pode "mudar isso" usando o próprio [`.Format()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format). Você só vai mudar quando for exibir a data, no caso.

---

Considerando que tenha:

```
type SeuStruct struct {
    Data time.Time
}
```

Então bastaria usar o `seuStruct.Data.Format`, como:

```
func main() {
    // Considerando que o `SeuStruct` fosse o seu struct
    ss := &SeuStruct{Data: time.Now()}

    // Formata como quer exibir:
    fmt.Println(ss.Data.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
}
```

O `2006-01-02 15:04:05` define o formato, você pode ver a documentação em https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants.

Comment: Entendi! Existe alguma maneira eficiente de eu padronizar esse formato no retorno de uma query por exemplo? Porque o que penso em fazer é iterar todo o slice retornado pela query e dar o `.Format()` no campo que é time.Time, mas não me parece eficiente isso.

Comment: Se está preocupado com performance, nesse nível, não use `time.Time` em primeiro lugar, a conversão já ocorre ao tornar o TIME/DATE/TIMESTAMP/DATETIME em `time.Time`. Se não quer a conversão para `time.Time` remova o `parseTime=True` (ou equivalente, ao iniciar a conexão com banco de dados) e use `string`. Também pode usar o próprio `DATE_FORMAT()` do MySQL (ou equivalentes) e retornar como string, de qualquer forma conversão vai ocorrer. Eu uso `time.Time`, ele também implementa o `.MarshalJSON` e o `.GobDecode` então o `json.Encoder()`/`gob.Encoder()` funciona diretamente.

Comment: Certo, me ajudou bastante sua explicação, muito obrigado!